# How do I do this SQL SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a table called SPJ with SNo, PNo, JNo and Quantity. The SQL statement problem is:

**Get the supplier number of suppliers who supply part P3 but do not supply part P5.**

Now I'm sure this should be simple, but i cannot get it to return the right results!

It should just return "S3", as they are the only ones who supply part 3 but not 5, yet it always returns the number of suppliers who supply both, no matter what combination of NOT, <> etc is used.

Comment: Two things will make it a good question. (1) Sample Data, (2) the query that you have tried.

Comment: its actually sample questions for exam revision...

Comment: what - SNo, JNo but not Qty but Quantity - i dont believe it

Comment: yeh sorry its actually qty, although that holds no relation to the question. i simply added that for completeness and understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  sno
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT sno
        FROM    spj
        WHERE   pno = 3
        ) q
WHERE   sno NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  sno
        FROM    spj
        WHERE   pno = 5
        )
```

Comment: @Chris Edwards That 'q' is an alias for the subquery. You'll get a syntax error (in some DBMSes, at least) without it. Note the same isn't needed for a subquery in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the EXCEPT clause.

It's a two step thing.  You need to compile the list for Part 3, and have a separate list for Part 5 that is then removed.  the EXCEPT clause is one way to do this.  Or you can use "Where not exists"

Comment: `MySQL` does not support `EXCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct sno  # distinct in case of duplicates
from spj A
left join spj B on A.sno = B.sno and B.pno = 5  # same supplier supplies part 5
where A.pno = 3  # supplies part 3
  and B.sno is null  # no match on left join
```